# add_filter adds output in the head

Tags: plugin-development, filters, the-content

I build plugin and I have a problem

I add to plugin:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', myFunction);
function myFunction()
{
    $options = get_option('myPlugin_settings');
    if (is_page($options['myPlugin_list'])) {
        echo"--------------------------------------------------------";
    }
}
```

and I see the `--....` also in the head.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filters should `return` their content, and not `echo` it. That is why you see the output in your head as well

### EDIT

I really have no idea why you would want to use `require` or `include` in your filter.

Here is an example of your filter should be coded

```
add_filter( 'the_content', myFunction );
function myFunction( $content )
{
    $options = get_option('myPlugin_settings');
    if ( is_page( $options['myPlugin_list'] ) ) {
        return "--------------------------------------------------------";
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Yes but I have the same problem if I use `require` or `include`